# F#: How to Generate XML using a complex XSD

Tags: xml, f#, xsd

I am trying to use F# to generate XML, based on this complex XSD Schema (
http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/exibirArquivo.aspx?conteudo=BALgvpK9Jvo= ) 
but I am getting compiler error:

> FS0503    A member or object constructor 'Dest' taking 0 arguments is not
>   accessible from this code location. All accessible versions of method
>   'Dest' take 1 arguments.

I think I gave all correct arguments:
[image: Visual Studio Tooltip]

```
module xsd1

open FSharp.Data
open System.Xml.Linq

type nfe = XmlProvider<Schema="nfe_v4.00.xsd", ResolutionFolder="c:/temp/nfe">

let GenerateNFe () =
    let ide = Unchecked.defaultof<nfe.Ide>
    let emit = Unchecked.defaultof<nfe.Emit>
    let mydest = nfe.Dest(cnpj=None,
                          cpf=(Some "12345678901"),
                          idEstrangeiro=None,
                          xNome=(Some "TONY"),
                          enderDest=None,
                          indleDest="",
                          ie=None,
                          isuf=None,
                          im=None,
                          email=(Some "tonyvca@oldmail.com")
                         )

    let i = nfe.InfNFe(
                       versao="4.00", 
                       id="NFe123 F#",
                       ide=ide, 
                       emit=emit, 
                       avulsa=None, 
                       dest=(Some mydest), 
                       retirada=None, 
                       entrega=None, 
                       autXmLs=Unchecked.defaultof<nfe.AutXml[]>, 
                       dets=Unchecked.defaultof<nfe.Det[]>, 
                       total=Unchecked.defaultof<nfe.Total>, 
                       transp=Unchecked.defaultof<nfe.Transp>, 
                       cobr=None, 
                       pag=Unchecked.defaultof<nfe.Pag>, 
                       infAdic=None, 
                       exporta=None, 
                       compra=None, 
                       cana=None                       
                      )
    i
```

How can I fill the dest "property" ?

I also can not change it

```
let ChangeDest (n: nfe) =
    let novodest = nfe.Dest(cnpj=None, 
                            cpf=Some "9999999999",
                            idEstrangeiro=None, 
                            xNome=Some "NEW TONY", 
                            enderDest=None,
                            indleDest=None,
                            ie=None,
                            isuf=None, 
                            im=None, 
                            email=Some "tonyvca@freemail.com"
                            )
    let newdocument = { n with InfNFe.dest = novodest }
    newdocument
```

To make easier, I attached a sample Project with the XSD and the F# code
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IbMpmOKfh4B-gKj4CCXTuDXlQxyUN1Wr

This does not work:

```
let mydest = new nfe.Dest(cnpj=None, cpf=(Some "11111111111"), idEstrangeiro=None, xNome=(Some "TONY"), enderDest=None, indleDest="indledest", ie=None, isuf=None, im=None, email=(Some "tonyvca@hotmail.com") )
```

But this works:

```
let mydest = new nfe.Dest(None, (Some "11111111111"), None, (Some "TONY"), None, "indledest", ie=None, isuf=None, im=None, email=(Some "tonyvca@hotmail.com") )
```

If I remove named parameters, up to the **indleDest** part, it Works, can you give a look and help me how to make it work will all named parameters written?

Comment: `indleDest` should be a string, not a string option. Unfortunately, when you use the wrong type within the constructor of a provided type you don't get helpful error message.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! But after I fixed it still get that error message

Comment: Try putting parens around anything with a space in it: e.g. `(Some "12345678901")`. I remember needing that sometimes. Does that help?

Comment: The parenthesis did not seem to solve that error.

Comment: Can you try passing values without naming arguments? I know it's less readable and more error prone, but it's just yet another attempt. Unfortunately I have no access to my PC so I can't help much more at the moment

Comment: Thank you for attention, is there some blog posting with more details on generating XML output having a complex Schema like mine, and also setting parts of the data?

Comment: Don't know of any relevant post, but you may write one once you've sorted out how to do it! As for setting parts of the data, it may be tricky but doable. Hint: take advantage of the xelement property which is mutable, while the other ones are just views on the xelement

Comment: Giacomo, If I remove named parameters, to the indleDest part, it Works, can you give a look and help me how to make it work will all named parameters written?

Comment: I found the problem: Due to a font problem and lack of autocompletion for parameter names, I was typing indleDest (INDLEDEST) but the correct was indIeDest (INDIEDEST) , now it compiles fine! :D

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: 
Due to a font problem and lack of autocompletion for parameter names, I was typing indleDest (INDLEDEST) but the correct was indIeDest (INDIEDEST), now it compiles fine! :D

```
let mydest = nfe.Dest(cnpj=None,
                      cpf=(Some "81679580515"),
                      idEstrangeiro=None,
                      xNome=(Some "TONY"),
                      enderDest=None,
                      indIeDest="",
                      ie=None,
                      isuf=None,
                      im=None,
                      email=(Some "tonyvca@hotmail.com")
                     )
```